# Удалить ненужный html комментарий в строке при парсинге

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Всем здравствуйте при парсинге столкнулся стем, что  на выходе в строке появляются ненужные html комментарии. Вот ищу выход как убрать это с помощью парсера или все таки нужно убирать или регексом.
Использую HtmlAgilityPack. Вот сам метод парсинга категорий с сайта.

```
 public async Task<List<Rubriks>> GetRubrik(string url)
        {

            List<Rubriks> Rubruks = new List<Rubriks>();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument Doc = new HtmlDocument();
            Doc.LoadHtml(await this.c.Getpage(url));

            var c = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='categoryTreeFull']/tbody/tr/td/a");

            foreach (HtmlNode n in c)
            {
                if (n.Attributes["href"] != null)
                {
                    string urrl = n.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    string url_text = n.InnerText;
                    // добавили рубрики
                    Rubruks.Add(new Rubriks() { UrlRubrik = urrl, NameRubrik = url_text });
                }


            }

            return Rubruks;
        }
```

И тут при парсинге в string url_text = n.InnerText;
вот такое значение `"Бухгалтерия, финансы и экономика предприятия<!--<strong></strong>-->"`. 
Вопрос: можно ли как то убрать `<!--<strong></strong>-->"` с помощью парсера.
Сайт который я парсирую https://www.rabota66.ru/resume тут список рубрик. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: `myString.Replace(" </strong>-->", String.Empty)`? А вообще есть пример входных данных? Вы показали какой то обрывок непонятно чего, там и комментария то нет

Comment: [How to remove comments from Html using html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-remove-comments-from-html-using.html)

Comment: @tym32167 Он не выделил HTML  кодом, поэтому он некорректно отобразился.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight окей, спасибо

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ответ и за ссылку.